# How to animate tableView cells when they change order?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am currently working on a app that shows nearby annotations to user by TableView. Cells are ordered by distance to user's location. I want to animate the cells when they change order due to distance. How can I do that ?

[Here's my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPegX.jpg)

I had tried this code but it didn't work.

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.moveRow(at: IndexPath(row: fromIndex, section: 0), to: IndexPath(row: toIndex, section: 0))
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Edit : I tried like this one it didn't work like the way I want, but it was really close. The problem is, all the cells are animating when a single cell changes it's order

didUpdateLocations :

```
sortedAnnotationArrayWithModel = annotationArrayWithModel.sorted { $0.distance < $1.distance }
        tableView.reloadData()
        tableView.beginUpdates()
            for i in 0..<sortedAnnotationArrayWithModel.count {
                let oldIndex = annotationArrayWithModel.firstIndex(of: sortedAnnotationArrayWithModel[i])
                let newIndex = i
                if oldIndex != newIndex {
                    tableView.moveRow(at: IndexPath(row: oldIndex!, section: 0), to: IndexPath(row: newIndex, section: 0))
                }
            }
        tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Please review [ask]. Describe what type of animation you want to achieve. Show the code you tried that "didn't work."

Comment: @DonMag, I'm pretty sure the OP is just asking how to do standard animation of reordering cells. That is built-in behavior for UITableView.

Comment: What happens with the code you tried? Did it show errors? Did it change the rows without animation?

Comment: Please note that the statement "didn't work" isn't useful. Please be specific. In what way didn't it work? Did you get a compiler error? Runtime error? Unexpected behavior? Please update your question with specific details about what happened versus what you want to happen.

Comment: @batudmrc - your code works fine in a test case. Worth noting -- the animation is different, depending on the visibility of `fromIndex` and `toIndex`. Also, the default animation is pretty quick... you can "slow it down" by wrapping it in a `UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, ...` block. Also, begin/end updates is not needed.

Comment: I found the code to animate but now I need logic to only animate the cells that changed their order

Comment: @batudmrc - your "re-ordering" code *looks* correct... I suspect the issue of *"all the cells are animating when a single cell changes it's order"* is due to the fact that you'll never have **just a single cell** moving. At a minimum, say moving from closest to 0 to closest to 1, you have both "`at: 0, to: 1` ***and***  `at: 1, to: 0`. Depending on the arrangement of your annotation locations, it might just be the case that proximity is changing more often (or relative to more locations) than you expect.

Comment: @batudmrc - as I mentioned, the from-to animation will be different (and can look very awkward) depending on the current table state. For example, if the user has scrolled the table down to, say, row 3, and `row 0` needs to move, `row 0` doesn't exist yet -- so there is nowhere for it to "animate from." If you're interested, I can post an answer that uses (what I consider) a much easier and more consistent approach.

Comment: @DonMag that will be great I'm waiting for your answer. Thanks

Comment: @batudmrc - I have an example that simulates walking around a map of "landmarks" -- but I want to also show you a clear, simple example. Just taking a little time.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your changes in a call to `performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)`

You pass that function a closure that does the reordering, and it animates the changes.

Comment: If this would work, explain why `beginUpdates` / `endUpdates` doesn't.